# How to use vlookup formula to look at two values before displaying a value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I want my vlookup formula to first look for a date (column A), then look for a person's name (column B), then display the value of column C. I can get the formula to display the person's name (column B) but not sure where to go from here...

```
=VLOOKUP(L5, {DATA!A:A, DATA!B:B}, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E2&F2, {A:A&B:B, C:C}, 2, 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E&F2:F, {A:A&B:B, C:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]